# How to add "Login via MySite.com" button to Java app? Browser is opening, user signed in and then site return him back to app (with session id)

Tags: java, authentication, authorization

I need to add to my Java app [Login via MySite.com] button (like for example in Figma).

1. Browser is opening
2. User signed in on my site to his profile
3. Then my site return him back to app (and tells user's session id on my site to app)

I want to make single session between both browser and my app. So if user logout on site, his session also dropped in my app. And vice versa - if user logged out from my app, he also automatically logged out on site.

How to do that? I searched Google a lot, but found nothing about this authorization kind.

Comment: why don't you use java to do the login?

Comment: Because I want to avoid typing of login/password again and again in different places and "I want to make single session between both browser and my app. So if user logout on site, his session also dropped in my app. And vice versa - if user logged out from my app, he also automatically logged out on site"

Comment: I think you are missing the point.  Using Java API https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.html you can get the same information that the browser does (After all, the browser is just an application).  Otherwise you could try to use something like selenium.